# Style search results custom post type WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type called 'grhdogs'. The problem is that the loop inside the WordPress search.php is styling the custom post type like a normal hit on a post or page. I want to style the custom post type search results with a different template part. How can I do this? It speaks for it self that normal posts and pages should get the default template part (content,search).

This is the loop...

```
        <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'search' ); ?>      
                <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php else : ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php wplook_content_navigation('postnav' ) ?>
```

The template part I want to use for the custom post type 'grhdogs' is:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'search', 'grhdogs' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include the template part by comparing the post type using [get_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) function -

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php // so if the current post type is your custom post type ?>
    <?php if( 'grhdogs' == get_post_type() ): ?>      
        <?php get_template_part( 'search', 'grhdogs' ); ?>
    <?php // for any other post type ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'search' ); ?>      
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wplook_content_navigation('postnav' ) ?>
```

Additionally, For including separate template file based on post type and current object page, a dynamic method be -

```
<?php $query_type = 'search'; // pv: archive, author, category ?>
<?php $post_type = get_post_type(); // pv: post, custom post type ?>

<?php get_template_part( $query_type, $post_type ); ?>
```

And example template filename would be then - 'search-post.php'

** pv = possible value